# Finding a key corresponding to an approximate user input value

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I am tackling a problem with a dictionary containing a chemical reaction and its associated voltage. The dictionary is made from a .txt file, and I would very much like to be able to input a desired voltage (i.e. 2), and have the code give me the reaction with the value closest to the input.

The .txt file looks like this (shortened):

```
left side of reaction|right side of reaction|voltage. 
F2(g)+2e–|2F–(aq)|+2.87
Co3+(aq)+e–|Co2+(aq)|+1.82
Pb4+(aq)+2e–|Pb2+(aq)|+1.8
H2O2(aq)+2H+(aq)+2e–|2H2O|+1.77
```

I have made this code here to get the voltages as keys, and only the left side of reaction as a value.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import operator
with open('redoxacid.txt', 'r') as document:
    next(document)
    answer = {}

    for line in document:
        line = line.strip('\n')
        line = line.split('|')

        if not line:
            continue
        answer[line[0]] = line[2] #here we have the reactions as key, and volt as value.

res = dict((v, k) for k, v in answer.items()) #flipping values in dictionary


sorted(answer.items(), key=lambda x: x[-1])
#print(res)

userinput = input("Voltage? ")

for k, v in res.items():
    print(k,v) #I now have two values here, voltage and reaction



#?????
```

when I print I get this:

```
+2.87 F2(g)+2e–
+1.82 Co3+(aq)+e–
+1.8 Pb4+(aq)+2e–
+1.77 H2O2(aq)+2H+(aq)+2e–
+1.7 NiO2(s)+4H+(aq)+2e–
....and so on
```

How can I now take a user input(a number) and find the value most like it inside my dict/list ?

say if I take input = 2, then the code finds the value approximately equal to that and prints the corresponding reaction.

Comment: Perhaps you better first define when two values are *approximately the same*. This is in fact the core problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I suggest using a different data structure than a dict here for the following reasons:

The good thing about dicts is the quick access to elements when given a key. However, you don't know the key, you only know something that is close to the key - therefore you need to iterate over the dict anyways.

The problem with a dict is that it requires a certain voltage to only be associated with exactly one chemical reaction. Even if that is true for the subset of chemical reactions you use, I would still suggest you try to avoid this problem from the beginning.

Instead, why not use a list of tuples (here, we convert the voltage-strings from your input files into floats)

```
res = [(float(v), k) for k, v in answer.items()]
```

Now you have to define what it means for two voltages to be close. For example

```
def approximatelyEqual(v1, v2):
    epsilon = 0.001 # Define this however you want
    return abs(v1 - v2) < epsilon
```

Once you have this the rest is simple

```
similarChemicalReactions = [(voltage, reaction) for (voltage, reaction) in res if approximatelyEqual(voltage, userinput)]
```

gives you a list of approximately close chemical reactions. If you want the closest one, do:

```
similarChemicalReaction = min(((voltage, reaction) for (voltage, reaction) in res), key=lambda v1: approximatelyEqual(v1, userinput))
```

Comment: For the first one I get unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: For the second one I get invalid syntax somewhere around approximatelyEqual. I have no idea :/

Comment: Looks like the same issue my answer had, you have to convert the string values in your table/dict/tuple to a float. `float(string.strip('+-'))` will do it.

Comment: @ivdito is right, I changed my answer to adress that. You need to change the type of userinput as well, i.e. userinput = `float(input("Voltage? "))`

Comment: thanks you guys, I feel its almost there, but now I get 'int' object not callable in the similarchemicalreaction =

Comment: I tried to fix another operand type error in float(v1-v2), but it still gives me error : "unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'float' and 'str'. it happens where I say that epsilon is bigger than the difference in v1 and v2

Comment: might not have, now I am in here and it gives me 'int' object not callable

Comment: it works now for only negative values for userinput, whenever I try to just type the number 2, it gives me empty brackets []

Comment: Can you clarify which method you are using?

Comment: I am using:
    `similarChemicalReactions = [(voltage, reaction) for (voltage, reaction) in res if approximatelyEqual(voltage, userinput)]`

and now I always get empty brackets, whatever I type in for input.

Comment: I might just have been really stupid here, I chose a way too restrictive epsilon, sorry!!

Answer (score 1):

Iterate through your keys, calculate the absolute difference between each key and the user input, return the value for the minimum difference.

```
 min = 9999 # arbitrarily high minimum difference
 minKey = 0 # start (this is also arbitrary and will be replaced)
 for key in res: # iterate through dict keys
     if abs(userinput-float(res[key].strip('+-')))<min: # if key is closer than the previously-found closest key
         minKey = key # update minKey

 print res[minKey] # output result
```

Comment: hey, cheers, but I get this error if I try that: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

Answer (score 1):

This solution assumes that an approximate value occurs when the `abs(user_input_value - key_val) < 1`:

```
file_data = [i.strip('\n').split("|") for i in open('filename.txt')]
d = {float(c[1:]):a for a, b, c in file_data}
val = int(input("enter voltage: "))
possibilities = [b for a, b in d.items() if abs(val-a) < 1]
final_reactions = "None found" if not possibilities else ', '.join(possibilities)
```